# Why does SQLite not work in my Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an app in android studio with sqlite and it doesnt work. I created a new project to test sqlite, but again it didnt work. Then I created a simpler app with sqlite to avoid mistakes, but it still didnt work. The application just keeps stopping. Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

There is app [logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjUFT.png)

Logcat:

```
2019-01-19 16:52:48.127 1605-1605/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-01-19 16:52:48.127 1605-1605/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-19 16:52:48.141 1605-18287/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xdf9836c0 tid=18287 ready to run
2019-01-19 16:52:48.143 3235-17962/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
2019-01-19 16:52:48.144 3235-17962/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-19 16:52:48.156 3235-17962/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-19 16:52:48.160 3235-17962/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
     com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.k.a(SourceFile:91)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.l.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.b(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.c.call(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.j(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:17)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
```

And many more lines. If you want i can send you screens of logcat.
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText studentid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
EditText studentname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle save) {
    super.onCreate(save);
}

public void loadStudents(View view) {
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    first.setText(dbHandler.loadHandler());
    studentid.setText("");
    studentname.setText("");
}


public void addStudent(View view) {
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(studentid.getText().toString());
    String name = studentname.getText().toString();
    Student student = new Student(id, name);
    dbHandler.addHandler(student);
    studentid.setText("");
    studentname.setText("");
}
}
```

Student:

```
public class Student {
// fields
private int studentID;
private String studentName;
// constructors
public Student() {}
public Student(int id, String studentname) {
    this.studentID = id;
    this.studentName = studentname;
}
// properties
public void setID(int id) {
    this.studentID = id;
}
public int getID() {
    return this.studentID;
}
public void setStudentName(String studentname) {
    this.studentName = studentname;
}
public String getStudentName() {
    return this.studentName;
}
}
```

MyDBHandler:

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//information of database
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "StudentID";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "StudentName";
//initialize the database
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID +
            "INTEGER PRIMARYKEY," + COLUMN_NAME + "TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {}
public String loadHandler() {
    String result = "";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int result_0 = cursor.getInt(0);
        String result_1 = cursor.getString(1);
        result += String.valueOf(result_0) + " " + result_1 +
                System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
public void addHandler(Student student) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, student.getID());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, student.getStudentName());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
}
public Student findHandler(String studentname) {

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = " + "'" + studentname + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Student student = new Student();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        student.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        student.setStudentName(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        student = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return student;
}
public boolean deleteHandler(int ID) {

    boolean result = false;
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = '" + String.valueOf(ID) + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Student student = new Student();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        student.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {
            String.valueOf(student.getID())
        });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
public boolean updateHandler(int ID, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_ID, ID);
    args.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + ID, null) > 0;
}
}
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.testovanisql.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="15"
    android:id="@+id/id"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="15"
    android:paddingTop="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/name"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="save"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="addStudent"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="load"
    android:layout_below="@+id/save"
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="loadStudents"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why does you logs show audio flinger stuff? where is the error related to db?

Comment: And also, a wise person always avoids a problem. Use Room persistence library.

Answer (score 0):

i read your code. i think problem in upgrade method . try this code :

```
public class SQLitehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Demochat.db";
String TABLE_NAME = "chatdata";
String COL_1 = "ID";
String COL_2 = "TYPE";
String COL_3 = "DATE";
String COL_4 = "TIME";
String COL_5 = "MSG";



public SQLitehelper(MainActivity context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TYPE TEXT,DATE TEXT,TIME TEXT,MSG TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public  boolean insertData(String type, String date, String time, String msg){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,type);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,date);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,time);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,msg);
    long results=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(results==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor gtealldata(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, I forgotten write onUpgrade method, but it still not working

Comment: How? Only change number from 1 to 2?

Comment: yes, super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); change to 2

Comment: in sql any type of database query changes  need to update database version

Comment: @ellen thank you for your answer, i am going to try add spaces And download Setho, Vít I have alredy do IT step by step from android developer, but it Dora not work

Comment: I have tried change database version but after launch IT still stopped

Comment: i think problem in your mainactivity in oncraete method try thsis code :

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
}

Comment: in on create method load layout like this : setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

Comment: i see your logcat result and in which nullpointer exception in findviewbyid . add layout in mainactivty

Comment: Thank you, yes I have forgotten setcontentview. I have added it to code, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your database creation alone, I've spotted a few mistakes (mainly missing spaces). It should be:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE_TABLE =
             "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
```

I would advise you to have a look at the official documentation on how to build an SQLite database: [data storage SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).

It's usually best to go step by step: make sure your database is created properly first before you start adding to it. You can use simple yet useful tools like [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to check your database.

Also, you can filter your logcat by selecting "Show only selected application". [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwhAk.jpg)

Comment: @Vít Vohralík You're welcome (I can't comment on the other thread). Once you've updated your db schema, you'll have to either uninstall your app from your phone/emulator (whatever you use for testing) and reinstall it, or just clear the app data from the phone/emulator. No need to change the db version on an app that is only in its developing stage (i.e. has not neen released). You can also check this AndroidHive [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) for more help.